# Hosting urls in .net core

Tags: c#, .net

My .net core application is initialised from hosting.json file where is stored "server.urls".

And I need from my application to know this "server.urls". How can I get this data?

Comment: Why can't you load it to your configuration using `AddJsonFile("hosting.json")` (just like Kestrel does)?

Comment: thx! good ideea :) solved! :)